# Using both GORM & direct JPA/Hibernate datasource in Grails application

Tags: spring, grails, grails-orm

We are trying to upgrade our existing Grails application to 5.2.4

We have defined datasource properties in application.yml which gets used during GORM initialization. Rest of the application we use pure JPA/Hibernate (i.e. don't use GORM)
by using datasource defined in a spring style bean.

At high level, issue that we are facing is either GORM or JPA datasource is getting initialized correctly. But both data sources are not getting initialized at the same time.

If I add dependency following dependencies in gradle script,

1. org.grails.plugins:hibernate5
2. org.hibernate:hibernate-core:xxx.Final

Then GORM gets initialized correctly. But then we get following issue when doing JPA style queries
Caused by IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException:  is not mapped [select xxx]

2. If I remove those dependency, GORM queries fails with following error.

Either class is not a domain class or GORM has not been initialized correctly or has already been shutdown. Ensure GORM is loaded and configured correctly before calling any methods on a GORM entity.

It seems may be some configuration is missing, but nor sure where is the exact issue.

Appreciate any help/suggestions.

Comment: For the entities that you are mapping with what you call "pure JPA/Hibernate", are the source files for those entities under `grails-app/domain`?

Comment: No, source files for those entities are not under grails-app/domain. Those are in typical java source code directories i.e. src/main/java